# Поиск в приложении: Searchable Activity, Searchable Dialog

Tags: java, android

Хочу сделать поиск в определенной активити в приложении, немного запуталась в тьюториалах. Хочу добавить в `MainActivity`, стандартный поиск при нажатии на клавишу. Не могу понять, почему поиск не работает.

Добавила `searchable.xml`:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

Добавила в `Manifest` `meta-data`:

```
<activity android:name=".views.MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
            </activity>
```

Добавила функционал поиска при нажатии на кнопку:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search:
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                    String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
                    onSearchRequested();
                    return true;
                }
                default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

Код menu items xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_searched_24dp"
        android:title="search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" />
```

При нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит. Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот посмотрите это[Creating a Search Field in Your Android app.](https://androidhub.intel.com/en/posts/nglauber/Android_Search.html)
Можно реализовать первый самый простой вариант через интерфейс SearchView.OnQueryTextListener. В методе `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` добавьте:

```
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
```

Когда нажмете кнопку поиска сработает метод onQueryTextSubmit, там и пропишите свою логику. Если хотите через ContentProvider писать поиск, то посмотрите в статью. У вас многого не хватает